# How to make orderBy() order numbers after alphabetic characters?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

While trying to sort data in ascending order in DataWeave, I've noticed that if the input for orderBy() contains strings that start with numbers and alphabetic characters like `["6", "7", "a", "8"]`, then the result is `["6","7","8","a"]`.

Is there a way that we can have strings which are starting with alphabetic characters before numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in Unicode digits are before alphabet characters. You can use the criteria parameter of orderBy() to change the way numbers are going to be compared with characters. For example adding character `{` as a prefix which is a character that is just ufter `z` (lowercase z), then numbers will be after any alphabet characters.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import isNumeric from dw::core::Strings
---
payload orderBy (if (isNumeric($)) "{" ++ $ else $ )
```

Output:

```json
[
  "a",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8"
]
```

Comment: Awesome answer , I tried a variant of this , which worked as well
["6", "7", "a", "8"] orderBy(isNumeric($))

Comment: @StackOverflowed That will only work the numeric and non numeric elements are individually sorted in the original array. For example `["6", "7", "a", "8", "5"]` this will have `5` after 6, 7, and 8

Comment: additionally to what @HarshankBansal mentioned, isNumeric() returns a boolean. It is not clear how booleans are going to be sorted. If not explicitly defined the ordering may change in the future. Even if it is the intention of the ordering is not clear. I strongly recommend to be explicit in the intention of the code.